# Issue with forming logic

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, logic

***Sample ex. 1 :***

**STEP 1 : Original Sample i/p numbers :**  
621 
629 
6201    
6202    
6200    
623 
622 
6289    
6274    
6271    
6270    
628887  
62870   
625

**STEP 2 : Sorted no.s : These should be sort like this set of numbers(on the basis of considering as set of strings I got expected result like below) :**

My requirement is sort on the basis of string / but not on the basis of mathematical formula..

So for me java Arraysort is working fine here for getting expected output.
String invalid[] = {"621","629","6201","6202","6200","623","622","6289","6274","6271","6270","628887","62870","625"};
        Arrays.sort(invalid);

**Sorted i/p no.s :**

6200    
6201    
6202    
621 
622 
623 
625 
6270    
6271    
6274    
62870   
628887  
6289    
629

**STEP 3 : This is the step where I actually stuck since long time..

Below are the set of output numbers which I expect in the final result from the list of numbers mentioned in STEP 2**

Calculation basis is not on the basis of mathematical calculation method, so I'm need to build logic on the basis of expected output.

I need to consider previous number and next number of currently considered number and need add expected number in the output list. Need to also consider digit length and number at "n"th  digit to find next number.

Can get idea after analyzing output results.. 
**Expected o/p no.s :**

0   
1   
2   
3   
4   
5   
60  
61  
6203    
6204    
6205    
6206    
6207    
6208    
6209    
624 
626 
6272    
6273    
6275    
6276    
6277    
6278    
6279    
6280    
6281    
6282    
6283    
6284    
6285    
6286    
62871   
62872   
62873   
62874   
62875   
62876   
62877   
62878   
62879   
62880   
62881   
62882   
62883   
62884   
62885   
62886   
62887   
628880  
628881  
628882  
628883  
628884  
628885  
628886  
628888  
628889  
62889   
63  
64  
65  
66  
67  
68  
69  
7   
8   
9

Here is my attempt to get result mentioned in STEP 2 :
and it's working fine.. now this output will go as an input to STEP 3 program to get final outputas mentioned earlier.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //System.out.println("Hello");

    String invalid[] = {"621","629","6201","6202","6200","623","622","6289","6274","6271","6270","628887","62870","625"};
    Arrays.sort(invalid);

    for(int i=0;i<invalid.length;i++) {
        System.out.println(invalid[i]);
    }

    SortInvalidLevels obj1 = new SortInvalidLevels();
}
```

Comment: Where is your attempt ?

Comment: So you want to sort the numbers such that 62** is before 63?

Comment: yes.. my requirement is to sort on the basis of levels first and then apply mathematical formula to sort in ascending order where ever required. If my input is <0,55,7,80> then output should be <1,2,3,4,50,51,52,54,56,57,58,59,6,81 to 89, 9>

Comment: Suppose my input number set wd be <0,555,7,8> then output set wd be like this <1,2,3,4,50,51,51,53,54,550,551,552,553,554,556,557,558,559,56,57,58,59,6 and 9>

Comment: Main Funda/Trick is 0 to 9 numbers holds again 0 to 9 sub levels and likewise till nth digit level. e.g. 0 can be written like this <00,01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09> but it contains all sub levels so written only as 0 (this assumes that it holds range 0 to 9). Same applies to all numbers of "n" digit length.

Answer (score 0):

You can you a LinkedList. With the ListIterator returned by the method iterator() of this class you can access the previous and the next element, and you and add new element when you are interating it.
See ListIterator and LinkedList classes.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

```
Integer[] numbers = {2, 6, 62, 6255, 63, 9, 1, 12};
Arrays.sort(numbers, new Comparator<Integer>() {
     @Override
     public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
         return Integer.toString(o1).compareTo(Integer.toString(o1));
     }
});
```

Output:

```
[1, 12, 2, 6, 62, 6255, 63, 9]
```

In future, please post code you have tried as well with your question.

Comment: Yes It's right output till STEP 2, this output should go as a input to STEP 3 program to get final out put.

Comment: I am not seeing what's the difference between the output I have and the output in step 3

Comment: In your input you shouldn't include 1 and 12 at the same time., since if 1 is there means 1 holds all levels <10 to 19>.., so thet 12 shouldn't in your input list.

Comment: if your input is {2,6255, 63,9,12} then output set of numbers would be {0,10,11,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,3,4,5,60,61,620,621,623,624,6250,6251,6252,6253,6254,6256,6257,6258,6259,626,627,628,629,64,65,66,67,68,69,7 and 8}